# In Ansible, how to query hostvars to get a specific value of a key from a list item based on the value of a different key?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

**EDIT-UPDATE:**

I found a way to achieve what was trying to do, using the `index_of` plugin.  The following code outputs what I need.

```
---
- hosts: CASPOSR1BDAT003
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: false
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        mac_address: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][int_idx|int]['mac_address'] }}"
      vars:
        int_name: 'PCI1.1'
        int_idx: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.index_of', hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'], 'eq', int_name, 'name') }}"
    - debug:
        var: mac_address
```

Output:

```
PLAY [CASPOSR1BDAT003] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [ansible.builtin.set_fact] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [CASPOSR1BDAT003]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => 
  mac_address: 20:67:7C:00:36:A0
```

---

**What I am trying to do:**

- Use the Netbox dynamic inventory plugin (this works, brings back all the info I need)
- Query hostvars for a particular host, and get the value of the MAC address for a particular interface called PCI1.1

**What I have tried:**

1. Converting the hostvars to JSON and using json_query: this hasn't worked, and having looked at some issues on GitHub, hostvars isn't a "normal" dictionary. I've logged a couple of issues anyway (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76289 and https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/3706).
2. Use a sequence loop and conditional "when" to get the value - this sort of works when using the `debug` module, but still not just returning the value

**What works:**
I have tried the following, which outputs the `mac_address` variable as expected. The length of the list is found, and then the conditional matches the name.  I do get an warning about using jinja2 templating delimiters but that's not the target of this question.

```
---
- hosts: CASPOSR1BDAT003
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][{{ item }}]['mac_address']
      with_sequence: start=0 end="{{ end_at }}"
      vars:
        - end_at: "{{ (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'] | length) - 1 }}"
      when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][{{ item }}]['name'] == "PCI1.1"
```

The result is:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found:
hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][{{ item }}]['name'] == "PCI1.1"
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=0) 
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=1) 
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=2) 
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=3) 
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=4) 
ok: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=5) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][5]['mac_address']: 20:67:7C:00:36:A0
  item: '5'
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=6) 
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=7) 
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=8) 
skipping: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => (item=9)
```

I'm trying to use set_fact to store this `mac_address` variable as I need to use it in a couple of different ways.  However, I am unable to use `set_fact` on this (or any other hostvars data, it seems).  For example, the following:

```
---
- hosts: CASPOSR1BDAT003
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: false
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        interfaces: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][item]['mac_address'] }}"
      with_sequence: start=0 end="{{ end_at }}"
      vars:
        - end_at: "{{ (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'] | length) - 1 }}"
      when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][{{ item }}]['name'] == "PCI1.1"
    - debug:
        var: interfaces
```

results in:

```
fatal: [CASPOSR1BDAT003]: FAILED! => 
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute '5'
  
    The error appears to be in '/Users/kivlint/Documents/GitHub/vmware-automation/ansible/prepare-pxe.yml': line 19, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
  
    The offending line appears to be:
  
        #   when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][{{ item }}]['name'] == "PCI1.1"
        - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
          ^ here
```

If I hard-code the number 5 in, it works fine:

```
TASK [ansible.builtin.set_fact] ******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [CASPOSR1BDAT003]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [CASPOSR1BDAT003] => 
  interfaces: 20:67:7C:00:36:A0
```

If I use '5' as a var for the task, it also works.

```
---
- hosts: CASPOSR1BDAT003
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: false
  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        interfaces: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][int_index]['mac_address'] }}"
      vars:
        - int_index: 5
```

So I'm wondering, is this a "bug/feature" in how `set_fact` does or doesn't work with loops (meaning, the same loop worked fine with `debug`?  Or do I need to re-think the approach and consider trying to use `set_fact` to set a variable with the index of the list (e.g. 5 in the above example)? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on in your code, and achieving the result you want is simpler than you've made it.

Firstly, don't use `hostvars[inventory_hostname]`; plain variables are the ones belonging to the current host, and going through `hostvars` introduces some exciting opportunities for things to go wrong. `hostvars` is for accessing variables belonging to *other* hosts.

Secondly, using Jinja's built-in filtering capabilities avoids the need to worry about the index of the item that you want.

```
- hosts: CASPOSR1BDAT003
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: false
  vars:
    int_name: PCI1.1
    mac_address: "{{ interfaces | selectattr('name', 'eq', int_name) | map(attribute='mac_address') | first }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: mac_address
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a confusion between the [5] (6th item of a list) and ['5'] (a key named "5") ,
you see in your error: The error was: 'list object' has no **attribute '5'**.

with the module debug you have not error because [{{item}}] is replaced by [5] and not by ['5']. Its not the same thing with set_fact.

its the reason you have to use filter **int** to clarify the situation.

```
  - ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        interfaces: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][item|int]['mac_address'] }}"
      with_sequence: start=0 end="{{ end_at }}"
      vars:
        end_at: "{{ (hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'] | length) - 1 }}"
      when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][item|int]['name'] == "PCI1.1"
```

so i suggest you to use **loop** instead with_sequence:

```
- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    interfaces: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][item]['mac_address'] }}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, end_at|int, 1)|list }}"
  vars:
    end_at: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'] | length }}"
  when: hostvars[inventory_hostname]['interfaces'][item]['name'] == "PCI1.1"
```

Comment: Thanks!  That certainly works and answers why I got the error I initially had.  However, the answer by flowerysong (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69958617/10556530) both solves that and improves the code so have accepted that as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

`set_fact` works with loops, but not in a way you expect.

This example constructs list with loop from lists of dicts:

```
- set_fact:
    foo: '{{ foo|d([]) + [item.value] }}'
  loop:
    - value: 1
    - value: 2
```

Basically, each execution of set_fact creates a fact. You may refer to the same fact in jinja expression for `set_fact`, but you can't expect it to automatically build lists or something like that.